# Audiotrack setVolume - minimum value

Tags: android, audio, audiotrack

I am writing a simple app for testing hearing and I am generating pure tones with Audiotrack. Because it is an app for testing hearing I am using VERY low volume levels to play these tones.

To set volume I use audiotrack's **setVolume(float volumeValue)** method, where volumeValue = 0-1.

 I noticed the lowest volume I can get a device to play is about ~ 5.011872E-5. If I try to play sound with lower volume - e.g. 4.466836E-5, the sound is not played by the device. There is no error, just simply device does not play it.

Is it normal? Is there some kind of minimum limit level for Audiotrack volume value? Or maybe it's hardware connected issue - device cannot reproduce such quiet sounds?

Answer (score 1):

You need to `setVolume` as two digit float value for example `0.02f`.